# C# Is it possible to close that process?

Tags: c#, process

I have this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "samp.exe";
    string arguments = "arguments...";
    p.Exited += new EventHandler(p_Exited);
    p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
    p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    p.Start();
}
```

And

```
void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("it works");
}
```

It works, but when I launch `samp.exe`, the name changes to `gta_sa.exe`. I want to check if `gta_sa.exe` process was closed, then close my app.

**SHORTLY:** I want to make a button. When I click on, it launches `samp.exe` process, but `samp.exe` renames to `gta_sa.exe`, so I need to check if `gta_sa.exe` process was closed, close my app (Test.exe)

My code is closing `samp.exe`, but I want to close `gta_sa.exe`.

Answer (score 3):

> It work's, but when launches samp.exe, name changes to gta_sa.exe.

It sounds like samp.exe is a launcher for gta_sa.exe.  That is, the first process starts the second process.  If samp.exe does not wait for gta_sa.exe to exit, you will have to find the running instance of gta_sa.exe.  You can then [create a Process instance from the running process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9(v=vs.110).aspx) and add an event handler for Exited.

> P.S my code closing samp.exe, but I wan't to close gta_sa.exe..

No, it is not.  Your code is being alerted when samp.exe closes on its own (or for some other reason).  If samp.exe is indeed a launcher, its normal behavior would be to close after it starts gta_sa.exe.

If you want to close gta_sa.exe, you can do that using [Process.Kill()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can set an event handler for gta_sa.exe closing like this

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("gta_sa.exe");
foreach (var p in processes)
{
    p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    p.Exited += new EventHandler(p_Exited);
}
```

Make sure you wait to run this code until after gta_sa.exe has been started.  Normally there will be only one item in processes, the one process that was launched by samp.exe.

Comment: yep, but I'm newbie, can somebody create code for me? :((

Comment: Everything you need is more-or-less in the MSDN example I linked to.  Have a look at that example, and do your best to write the code.  If you are stuck writing that code, post a new question with your attempt at the code.

Comment: I know that process kill(), but I need other... I'm asking how to close my current form.exe when gta_sa.exe closes.

Comment: Well then your current approach will work, except you need to get a Process instance for gta_sa.exe using the method shown in the MSDN example.

Comment: The MSDN link *has* example code - you need to get an instance of `Process` in order to invoke `Kill` on it, which is what's shown there.

Answer (score 0):

When your samp.exe process exits try to get "gta_sa.exe" process and terminate it:

```
void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("gta_sa.exe");
    foreach (var process in processes)
        process.Kill();
}
```